# Unix base64 encoding mismatch

Tags: java, python, linux, unix, base64

I've been seeing some discrepancies in the base64 encoding in many utils from the unix util 
for ex: 
in java and python if I encode `b` I get `Yg==` but in unix I get `Ygo=`
I need to use b64 from unix in java and python. How do I make them consistent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppress the newline.

```
echo -n "b" | ...
```

Or add it.

```
>>> 'b\n'.encode('base64')
'Ygo=\n'
```

Comment: Good lord! tore out my hair for more than an hour. Thank you very much :)